# Crop multiple images one at a time with JCrop and session in php

Tags: php, jquery, image, crop, jcrop

I have an image crop script that crops one image at a time using the [Jquery Jcrop plugin](http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop.html).
now I want to upload more images and crop them one by one using a for loop.

What is the best way to do this?

I set my input field to multiple so it could upload more than one.

### EDIT:

I've editted my code below with a `$max` and `count`. and I think I'm doing it wrong. how can I fix it so when I click crop, it crops them after each-other.

This is my `uploaded.php`:

```
    <?php 
         session_start();
         $max = count($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
         for($i = 0; $i < $max; $i++){
            $target = $_FILES['file'][$i];
         }

         $target = "data/uploads/"; 
         $target = $target . basename( $_FILES['filename']['name']) ; 
         $_SESSION['target_path'] = $target;

         $ok=1; 
         if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'], $target)) 
         {
             echo "De afbeelding *". basename( $_FILES['filename']['name']). "* is geupload naar de map 'uploads'";
         } 
         else 
         {
             echo "Sorry, er is een probleem met het uploaden van de afbeelding.";
         } 
    ?>
```

Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure if people are going to read through blocks of codes. Can you refine the question by isolating the critical parts of the process?

Comment: people need all the code so it's clear. i editted it so that my question is at the top and the codeblocks at the bottom

Comment: Sorry, but your code does not belong too your question. Why do you print PHP-code, when you wish to do jQuery stuff. Please be more specific!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check a few things

1) To upload files, read: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php - specifically `input name="userfile[]"` in HTML and files on server show up as `$_FILES['userfile']['name'][0],...,$_FILES['userfile']['name'][N]`

2) `move_uploaded_file()` is a security check to ensure files are valid, dont leave home without it :-)

3) I'd recommend `imagemagick` library (http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.cropimage.php), I know, Jcrop demo uses GD library but worth your time looking at imagemagick.

4) Lastly if all fails, use `print_r($variable)` to ensure the files are getting into your server.

5) Sometimes it could be system admin issue like unwritable /tmp folder, disk full, upload size limit in php.ini and web server built-in timeout. Checking phpinfo() helps too

Comment: Awesome will try this things. hopefully i can fix it now.

Comment: i can't try it now. i will try it in a few hours.

Comment: i need a better solution. it's not going to work because i'm almost finished. i just need a forloop where the jcrop plugin crops images straight after eachother when clicking on crop.

Comment: On multi file upload, does it work with ONE file? Try making it work with one file then figure out why it fails for TWO files.

Comment: can't try it now. will do tommorrow

Comment: i just need to count the files. and then crop them 1 by 1. so the 5 in your code has to be someting like $max, and then first i have to do something like? $max = count($_FILES['userfile']['name']; ?

Comment: I never solved this problem, but I'm a lot more familiar with php and jquery now, So I could fix this myself if I needed to. Just want to let you know I know how to do this right now.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something more like this:

```
<?php 
session_start();

$upload_dir = "data/uploads/"; 
for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++){
     $target = $upload_dir . basename( $_FILES['file']['name'][$i]);
     if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i], $target)) {
         echo "De afbeelding *". basename( $_FILES['file']['name'][$i]). "* is geupload naar de map 'uploads'";
     } else {
         echo "Sorry, er is een probleem met het uploaden van de afbeelding.";
     }
}
```

Comment: tried this. but i get the error "Sorry, er is een prob....." 5 times. when i upload 5 images.

Comment: It would help to see the crop function too.